# Convert a color from the Color class into a human readable String

Tags: java, colors, awt

I wish to convert a Color Object into a human readable String.

To clarify I'm just looking for a conversion of the Class's static variables.

eg.

1. Color.YELLOW -> "yellow"
2. Color.RED -> "red"

```
Color red = Color.RED;
System.out.println(red.conversionMethod());
```

I want an output of "red"

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: If 255,0,0 is "Red", what is 254,0,0 called?  Do you expect 16,777,216 color names?

Comment: I'm just looking for a conversion of the Color Class's static variables and was wondering if there was a nice way of doing it.

Comment: toString() returns it in an RGB representation.

Comment: @patrick_corrigan I provided test code meeting your static variables requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get use of Java reflection. This code gives useful output. You can remove unwanted ones from ArrayList via something like `list.remove("BITMASK");`

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Test
{
    public static void main ( String [] args )
    {
        Field [] names = Color.class.getFields();
        ArrayList < String > list = new ArrayList < String >();

        for ( Field name: names )
            list.add( name.getName() );
        for ( int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++ )
            System.out.println( list.get( i ) );
    }
}
```

Output:

> white WHITE lightGray LIGHT_GRAY gray GRAY darkGray DARK_GRAY black
>   BLACK red RED pink PINK orange ORANGE yellow YELLOW green GREEN
>   magenta MAGENTA cyan CYAN blue BLUE OPAQUE BITMASK TRANSLUCENT

Comment: @patrick_corrigan There is no direct way. You've either have to go the way deporter shows you and use reflection to read the constant name (which are the color names, too) or you've to create a map on your own manually.

Comment: @FabianBarney Thank you for your explanation.I don't understand how to use the code above for my need.

Comment: You will just prepare a hash map matching the color names with the Color objects.